# Sharing webpage with selected text--how to get a quote in the Notes app

Tags: safari, sharing

I noticed whenever I'm in mobile safari about to share a webpage that has text selected if I select the share for Messages app it embeds a quote of the selected text like seen in the first image below which has the quote

> Today's news reinforces that doing it the hard way was the right decision.

However if I share the same selected text and website in the Notes app the quote is absent. Is there a configuration or some means to accomplish getting the quote embedded like how the Messages app does it?

[image: selected text shared as quote in messages]

[image: webpage shared in notes]